# ¿Cómo mostrar información en un Textbox C# Windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, textbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Requiero mostrar una contraseña en 1 Textbox el de abajo, si la información escrita en otro Textbox(el de arriba) es válida que al dar clic en el botón muestre la contraseña que deseo. La contraseña no está ligada a 1 base de datos.

Se me ocurre introducir el código en el botón recuperar:

Accionar si el texto escrito en textbox 1 es igual al deseado, entonces mostrar en textbox 2 la contraseña.

```
private void btn_recuperarudes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txb_recufecha.Text == "012685")
            
        }
```

Pero no se que mas codigo poner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un condicional como estabas intentando:

```
private void btn_recuperarudes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txb_recufecha.Text == "012685")
        {       
          txb_contraseña.Text = "tucontraseña";
        }
        else
        {
          "la acción que desees hacer si no es correcta la contraseña"  
        }               
    }
```